# How To Avoid Certain CSS coding/commands From Overriding Existing Customisations

Tags: html, css

I have a blog - http://www.blankesque.com. I have applied the following css coding to all links present on the blog.

```
a:hover {
font-weight: bold;
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
text-decoration: none;
}
```

With this piece of coding I wanted the color of the links to change slightly when a cursor hovers, which it does. However my issue is that this command/coding has applied to all links throughout my blog, including links that I didn't particularly want this feature for. There are two links where I would like the font-color to remain at #333333 and not have the opacity:0.6 have effect. The codings to these specific links are stated below:

```
.jump-link a:hover {
background: #fdfdfd;
border: 1px solid #fdfdfd;
}

a.button:hover {
background: #fdfdfd;
border: 1px solid #fdfdfd;
text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

I have tried to override the coding with the following pieces of commands however none have worked.

```
color: #333333!important
font-color:#333333!important
font:#333333!important
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Iram

Comment: Where did you put the overriding styles?  They should appear after the initial styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the opacity to 1 for the a:hover that is specific to the links that you don't want to have that effect on. Also, make sure it occurs afterwards in the stylesheet so that it doesn't get overridden.